# wsdl client java

Tags: java, wsdl, client

I have created web service client using NetBeans.

Some of the code:
...

```
mtsvmi.MGWPUBLICFUNCTIONSService service = new mtsvmi.MGWPUBLICFUNCTIONSService();
        mtsvmi.MGWPUBLICFUNCTIONSPortType proxy = (service.getMGWPUBLICFUNCTIONSPort());
        ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
        ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password"); 

        QName portQName = new QName("http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/SISTEMA_MOKA/MGW_PUBLIC_FUNCTIONS", "MGW_PUBLIC_FUNCTIONSPort");
        String req = "<INSERT_RECEIVES  xmlns=\"https://IP:PORT/orawsv/test/SISTEMA_MOKA/MGW_PUBLIC_FUNCTIONS\"><parameters>"+pingKonteineris+"</parameters></INSERT_RECEIVES>";

        try { // Call Web Service Operation
            Dispatch<Source> sourceDispatch = null;
            sourceDispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, Source.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);
            Source result = sourceDispatch.invoke(new StreamSource(new StringReader(req)));
//            System.out.println("---Ans: "+result.toString()+"---");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

...

gives me:

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

What did I do wrong? How do I fix this? What other info do you need to help me out in here?

Answer (score 1):

The `ConnectException` you get means that your app was not able to establish a socket connection to its target.  Typically this means that you've given the wrong hostname or port, or that the service on the other end isn't running.

From what you've posted it's not clear exactly what line of code threw the failure, or what address the connection attempt was made to.  However I would hazard a guess that it's the line where you call `sourceDispatch.invoke` - and that the `MGWPUBLICFUNCTIONSService` class is responsible for providing the address.

I suggest that you look into the logs, error messages and/or configuration to find out what address is being used and why a connection can't be established to that address.  Using `telnet` to try and establish connections yourself may be very helpful in preliminary investigation.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really tell you that - the proxy settings depend on the network between you and the target; I don't know what the target server is; and I don't know enough about the architecture of your project to know where it needs to be set.  But I can tell you that if you're using the literal string `http(s)://<server name>:<port>/orawsv/SISTEMA_MOKA/MGW_PUBLIC_FUNCTIONS` as the URL that's your problem right there, you'll need to substitute in the right protocol, host and port.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. and i resolved it by changing in .wsld file

```
<service name="CalculatorService">
    <port binding="tns:CalculatorPortBinding" name="CalculatorPort">
        <soap:address
            location="http://localhost:6060/WebServiceProject/CalculatorPort" />
    </port>
</service>
```

whre my port number was 8080 and changed to 6060 which i am using.

may it ll help u. try it.